# Unclosed expression sequence error when setting statusline?

Tags: buffers, statusline

I am trying to display the number of loaded buffers on my statusline using:

```
...
set statusline += %{len(getbufinfo({"buflisted":1}))}
...
```

The error I get is :

```
E540: Unclosed expression sequence: statusline +=%{len(getbufinfo({
```

What could I be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"` starts a comment in VimScript. Please, take your time reading `:h :comment` and `:h :bar` and remembering the rules.

You must either escape it with backslash or use another command that accepts quote as part of argument.

UPD. Also, you're not allowed to have nested braces here (thanks to @filbranden for spotting this). And so we have

```
"WRONG
set statusline+=%{len(getbufinfo({"buflisted":1}))}
"RIGHT
set statusline+=%{ListedBuffers()}
function! ListedBuffers() abort
    return len(getbufinfo({'buflisted': 1}))
endfunction
```

In practice, it could be easier to compute the whole status line by a function

```
set statusline=%!MakeStatusLine()
function! MakeStatusLine() abort
    let l:value = ...
    let l:value .= len(getbufinfo({'buflisted': 1}))
    ...
    return l:value
endfunction
```

Comment: This is good, but I think there's more... When using `:set`, you can't have spaces between the option and the operator (`=` or, in this case, `+=`), or between the operator and the value. (Actual spaces need to be escaped with `\\`.)

Comment: thanks. I never considered that `buflisted...` was bring commented out because I had used double and single quotes quite interchangeably while passsing arguments to functions prior to this (and had never faced this issue). I'll be careful in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @filbranden Ah, yes, I simply copy-pasted from the first code line. But, looking at error message, that was already fixed.

Comment: There are more issues though... A `%{...}` expression can't have a dict (which also uses `{...}`) inside it. You need to define a separate function to work around that...

Comment: @filbranden Oops. And this one looks buggy. Didn't even remember this one. Have to fix it somehow.